# Ошибка Python 3.8 inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я пишу Telegram бота и использую библиотеку TelegramBotAPI.
Но возникла проблема. Вылезает ошибка

File "main.py", line 61
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True*)*

TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.

Помогите пожалуйста.
Если, что использую Sublime Text

Часть кода которая не работает:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
try:
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'children':
            # Клавиатура
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Test1")
            item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Test2")

            markup.add(item1, item2)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Мы превратим увлечение ребенка компьютером в полезные навыки для будущего. Наши преподаватели переключат внимание детей с игр на разработку собственных проектов, познакомят с новыми технологиями, разовьют нестандартное мышление и опыт работы в команде.".format(
        message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
        elif call.data == 'adults':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Это комплекс знаний, умений, навыков, которые никогда не оставят Вас без работы. Диплом международного образца, сертификаты Microsoft, Cisco, Autodesk, наработанное портфолио. Все это позволит нашему выпускнику успешно трудоустроиться как в крупные локальные компании, так и в международные корпорации.')

        # Удаление кнопок
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Есть две программы обучения. Выберите о какой хотите узнать",
            reply_markup=None)

except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
```

Comment: *inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation* - проверьте, что везде используются либо табы, либо пробелы. Обычно IDE за этим следит.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот здесь у вас явно табуляции не хватает в строке перед `elif`:

```
        message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
        elif call.data == 'adults':
```

Должно быть так:

```
            message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
        elif call.data == 'adults':
```

Comment: Не работает.....

Comment: @ZZZ какую ошибку пишет - ту же?